# Prolog does not stop accepting data in read

Tags: prolog, decision-tree

This is my code in Prolog.

```
do(cinema):- parents(yes); (parents(no),weather(windy),money(less)).
do(play):- parents(no),weather(sunny).
do(stay):- parents(no),weather(rainy).
do(shopping):- parents(no),weather(windy),money(more).
start:- write('Parents: '),read(X),assert(parents(X)), write('Weather: '),read(Y),assert(weather(Y)), write('Money: '),read(Z),assert(money(Z)).
clear:- retract(parents(X));retract(weather(X));retract(money(X)).
```

I'm trying to accept data from user and then use decision tree to find out what task will be done.
I'm running the code as:

```
?-start, do(X).
```

But it does not write Weather after reading input for parents and keeps reading data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong with your program.  See http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/JDAJcUhq.pl.  The most likely cause is already mentioned: not finishing your term with a ".".  `clear/0` is indeed wrong, but not needed in the web version as each new query is executed in a fresh environment.

At least in SWI-Prolog there is no need to flush before a read operation from the terminal as flushing the console output streams is always done before the read.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems the problem was that I had not declared the methods, which you did in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some flush goals after the write goals and then remember to add a full stop on your input as you are using read/1 which wants a term.

Comment: You will also need to change retract to retractall btw and change to conjunction..